# Diminuir tamanho de pagina para impressão

Tags: javascript, html, css3, dom

Fiz uma função que imprimi uma div para mim, porém preciso que seja impresso no tamanho do tonner.

Este é o código:

```
$('#imprimirComprov').click(function () {
    var conteudo = document.getElementById('imprimir').innerHTML,
        tela_impressao = window.open('about:blank');

    tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
    tela_impressao.window.print();
    tela_impressao.window.close();
});
```

O tamanho que preciso é a do `a7 (74mm × 105mm)`

A imagem abaixo mostra como esta sendo mostrado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A altura não precisa ser levada em consideração, apenas a largura.

Este é o tamanho ideal para mim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar:  @media print, assim vai poder especificar o tamanho, segue um exemplo : 
[JSFIDDLE EXEMPLO](http://jsfiddle.net/929r3485/)

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Colega de qualquer jeito esta aparecendo a pagina no tamanho a4, tentei fazer algo para mudar isto porém não funcionou. Pode Observar que é diferente o tamanho das imagens e ate os espaços em brancos são menores.